# making a file executable via subprocess in python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to make a bash file executable via a python program. Right now it looks like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(chmod u+x, bashName)
```

`bashName` being the name of the bash file I'm making executable, and I'm receiving the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chmod u+x 
>        /home/#####/Desktop/music/addSong/bashFileName'

I've tried this and it didn't fare any better

```
subprocess.call('chmod u+x /home/stoplight25/Desktop/music/addSong/'+bashName)
```

I've tried reading the documentation on `subprocess` but it's a bit beyond my comprehension. Could someone explain how to make a file executable with `subprocess`.

Expected:

- make a new bash file with the correct contents and name, make it executable

Result:

- a bash file with the right contents and name but isn't executable.

Comment: pass the arguments as a _list_ or use `os.chmod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import subprocess
command = 'chmod u+x /home/stoplight25/Desktop/music/addSong/' + bashName
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: thanks! because of you i was able to get the first version of my project finished! (https://github.com/Stoplight25/PlayMyMusic/tree/version-0.1-test-branch)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the arguments as a *list*, not as a string or python tries to pass the whole string with spaces & args & all to the system as the executable (or use `shell=True` which I don't recommend). Also check return code just in case:

```
subprocess.check_call(['chmod','u+x','/home/stoplight25/Desktop/music/addSong/'+bashName])
```

Or you could use pure python to access the file permissions (get file current permissions, add user execute mask, apply `os.chmod`):

```
import os

my_file = os.path.join('/home/stoplight25/Desktop/music/addSong',bashName)
new_mode = os.stat(my_file).st_mode | 0o100
os.chmod(my_file,new_mode)
```